# How to call method(s), when click (or mouseover) event occurred outside the block?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have examples. :)

The first, on Facebook: it's a triangle *(in the top-right corner)* with drop-down menu *(where are placed "Log out", "Help", "Account Settings" buttons)*. So, if I'll place cursor outside this menu, it will be hidden.

I made it (hide block `onmouseover`), but when I'm placing cursor on child elements, `mouseover` event triggers.

The second, vk.com boxes. If I'll click outside this box, it's will be hidden (if all inputs are empty).

[image]

I'm doing wrong:

```
<div id="box_layer" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
    <div id="box">Boxboxbox</div>
</div>
```

For 1st, I've googled `event.cancelBubble=true` (also `e.stopPropagation()`), but I don't know, how to use it (because, how I'm doing it, it doesn't work).

Comment: Does jQuery's `mouseover` and `mouseout` methods help you? http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/        http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: I want to solve this problem, without jquery..

Comment: At first, you have to put your event handlers into functions. That gives you more alternatives to handle events.

Comment: Yes, of course.
I've wrote code in question just for example. :)

Comment: So, there is one problem: which event should work first.
And When I have a block with mouseover event, when I'm placing cursor on child elements, this mouseover event triggers (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For boxes I've made a class, close function of it:

```
close: function(e,$type,$parameters) { //e is the event
  var el=e.target||e.srcElement;
  if (el.id=='box_wrap' || el.id=='box_layer' || el.id=='closebox_button') {
    box.chooseLayer($type).getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML=null;
    box.closeLayer($type);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood right your post, I think you need to use the mouseout instead of mouseover.

```
function forMouseOut(){
    e=window.event;
    if(!e) e=window.Event;
    if(your_block.contains(e.target || e.toElement)) return;// Prevents closing when over child elements
     /* check the inputs and return if empty */
     your_block.style.display='none';
     return;
}
```

Then I suppose you won't need onclick at all, because `your_block` will be closed as soon as the mouse pointer moves out of it.

Comment: Thanks. But onclick I need in boxes (so, I wouldn't close boxes by mouseout :)). But I've made it (code in my answer).

Comment: "If I'll click outside this box, it's will be hidden" I translated this sentence as you would like to close the box when clicking outside of it. I'm not very familiar with jQuery, but if the code is working, it is a good code. And the event target has supposed to be a main issue here anyway.